# Short Story about science study-reproduction crisis

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story, likely in a Dozois Year's Best anthology, about how what seemed to be a study-reproduction crisis in academia was revealed to actually be a universal rupture in the laws of science that made it so that every study done actually *changed* the way things worked.

I think the protagonist was an African scientist, who had to deal with the breakdown of his life's work.

Comment: I keep reading that title as that there's a science study about a reproduction crisis... :-P

Answer (score 7):

This is [What We Found](http://bestsf.net/geoff-ryman-what-we-found-fantasy-science-fiction-septoct-2011/) by Geoff Ryman.

> *Ryman takes us to Nigeria, gives us the texture and taste of that
>   country, and the strange family of the protagonist, a young man whose
>   scientific research provides the sfnal element to the story which is
>   otherwise largely domestic and familial. **His research suggests that
>   too much scientific study, too much replication, is affecting science
>   itself.** It’s not a full-on science story approach a la Benford, just
>   passing notes on the research to reflect on the story.*

It was collected in [The Year's Best Science Fiction: Twenty-Ninth Annual Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Year%27s_Best_Science_Fiction:_Twenty-Ninth_Annual_Collection) by Gardner Dozois which is probably where you read it.

Comment: Yes that’s the one!!!! Thank you!!